# What should one "do" to "strictify" a triangle of transformations coming from a lax commutative triangle of functors?

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, abstract-nonsense

I would like to apologize for this rather stupid abstract nonsense question.

Let $h=f\circ g$ for composable functors $f,g$; assume that there exist left or right adjoints to $f$ and $g$. Then it seems natural to say that the composition of adjunction transformations for $f$ and $g$ equals the one for $h$. Yet I am not quite sure that one can speak about a "strict" equality here since adjunction transformations (as well as adjoint functors) are only defined up to a (canonical) equivalence.

Now, suppose that $h$ is only isomorphic to $f\circ g$ (this is my situation; I would not like to enforce an equality here since I actually treat a lax commutative square of functors). Then the adjunction transformation for $h$ remains to be equivalent to the composition mentioned. Yet I want to "make" this equivalence a strict equality. What ("words") should I write to indicate that I make compatible choices in the corresponding equivalence classes of transformations?

Does there exist a (classical?) reference where questions of this sort are treated carefully?

Comment: What do you mean by “adjunction transformations”?  I’m not familiar with that terminology (and neither is Google, apparently).

Comment: Do you prefer "unit/counit of the adjunction"?

Comment: I don’t know, because I still don’t know what you mean by “adjunction transformation”!  I’m guessing that you mean or the natural isomorphism $\mathbb{C}(fx,y) \cong \mathbb{D}(x,gy)$ (often called *transposition*). If you mean this, or the unit/counit, then they *are* determined up to strict equality; i.e. if $f \vdash g$ is an adjunction, with unit $\eta$ (or counit $\epsilon$, or transposition $\varphi$), and $g'$ is another functor with $\alpha:g'\cong g$, then there are unique $\eta'$ ($\epsilon'$, $\varphi'$) making $g'$ an adjoint to $f$, and commuting with $\alpha$.

Comment: @Peter is $f \vdash g$ the same as $g \dashv f$, meaning that $g$ is left adjoint to $f$?

Comment: Yes; if we fix $f$ and its adjoint then the unit and the counit will be fixed also. Yet I am interested in the case when the adjoint to $f$ is not fixed.

Comment: I don't know why you would want to do this. If the data of an adjunction exists, it is unique in the strongest reasonable sense (up to a contractible space of choices), so there are no coherence issues.

Comment: @TimCampion: oops, that was a typo; I meant $\dashv$ throughout.  Mikhail: once again, PLEASE can you clarify precisely what you are referring to as the “adjunction transformation”?  It’s not standard terminology, and without knowing that, it’s very hard to answer your question.

Comment: The units of my adjunctions in the case when $f,g,h$ admit right adjoints (so that one can compose the units for $f$ and $g$).